# Cannot sent JWT in headers to the server

Tags: express, vue.js, jwt

I'm learning a fullstack app having Vue as front-end, express as back-end and Mongodb.
I have login form and did a simple authentication in the back-end, after user is authenticated i generate JWT and store in user browser, In user's route navigation guards i make a request to sent that token to be verified in the server before let user in protected route

```
{
    path: '/user',
    name: 'User',
    component: () => import('../views/User.vue'),
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')

      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/authorize', {headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }})

    }
  }
```

But i couldn't sent headers which included token to the server, it got `undefined`  So how to do this properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to authenticate, your header must have a key of Content-Type and a Value of application/json

Try using Postman to login. You should receive a JWT ${token} in the response.

Once you are authenticated, all of your requests must include the following Key/Value pairs in the header:

- Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
- Accept: application/vnd.api+json
- Authorization: Bearer ${token}

Note: You must include the text "Bearer " (with a space) in the Authorization header and it is case-sensitive.

Comment: I add Content-Type but it doesn't work and i did check in browser Network tab it doesn't include token with the request

Comment: When you authenticate to get a JWT, you only use the Content-Type header. Once you are authenticated and have the JWT, then you must use the Content-Type, Accept, and Authorization headers when browsing to other routes that require authentication. I don't use Vue, so I cannot help much there. But, you can use Postman to validate the API side first before working on Vue.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have tried with Postman and yeah i got the token